# While loop versus If statement in Binary Search Tree BST traversals in Python

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, binary-search-tree, inorder

I am confused why a `while loop` is causing infinite recursion on a binary search tree Inorder traversal when I have put the terminating condition in the `while loop`

```
def Inorder(self, vals):
        while(self.left != None):
            print("Going left value seen = ",self.left.val)
            self.left.Inorder(vals)
        # if self.val is not None:
        vals.append(self.val)
        print("vals=",vals)
        if self.right is not None:
            print("Going right value seen = ",self.right.val)
            self.right.Inorder(vals)
        #print("does this also gets executed");
        return vals
```

If I replace the while loop with the `if statement`, it works right. I have tested with insertion pattern

```
t = Node()
t.insert(20)
t.insert(6)
t.insert(35)
vals = []
t.Inorder(vals)
print(vals)
```

Here is the whole class including the test patterns

```
class Node(object):
    
    def __init__(self,val=None):
        self.val = val
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        #print("constuctor called")
        
    def insert(self,val):
        if not self.val:
            self.val = val #by virtue of constructor
            print("value inserted at root = ",val)
            return
        
        if val < self.val:
            if self.left:
                #print("self.left.val = ",self.left.val)
                self.left.insert(val)
                return
            self.left = Node(val)
            print("value inserted on left = ",val)
            return
        else:
            if self.right:
                #print("exists self.right.val = ",self.right.val)
                self.right.insert(val)
                return
            self.right = Node(val)
            print("value inserted on right = ",val)
            return



    def Inorder(self, vals):
        while(self.left != None):
            print("Going left value seen = ",self.left.val)
            self.left.Inorder(vals)
        # if self.val is not None:
        vals.append(self.val)
        print("vals=",vals)
        if self.right is not None:
            print("Going right value seen = ",self.right.val)
            self.right.Inorder(vals)
        #print("does this also gets executed");
        return vals
        

  
            
   
t = Node()
t.insert(20)
t.insert(6)
t.insert(35)
# t.insert(3)
# t.insert(8)
# t.insert(27)
# t.insert(55)
print(t.val)
vals = []
t.Inorder(vals)
print(vals)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have infinite recursion, but an infinite loop. The `while` is testing `self.left` which is not being changed in the loop... so if `self.left != None` is true once, it will always be true.

It should be an `if` instead of a `while`. The recursion will take  care of the actual walking down the tree.

Comment: @trincort I changed while loop variable inside the body. It is still not working because the pointer has moved. Any idea to make it work with the while loop

Comment: That is a different question. If you cannot make it work after debugging, then I suggest asking a new question about that specific problem.